# Use of dependent variables in `with` statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can one use multiple variables in a `with` block in a situation where variable depend on one another? Intuitively it should be the case although it sometimes doesn't work.

For example:

```
with MongoClient() as client, client['my_dbp'] as db:
```

Comment: Have you tried it? The Python REPL is cheap and easy.

Comment: Well, of course I have and it didn't work. I'm happy withe the answer from Tali, which explains the conditions that must be met.

Comment: Sure, but that has nothing to do with dependencies within the statement, just with requirements to use `with` at all.

Comment: Ah so the answer is incorrect? So is it at all possible?

Comment: The answer is correct, but the question is... misleading. If all objects support the context manager interface then it will work. Any lack of support will cause the entire statement to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but all your objects must conform to the `__enter__`/`__exit__` protocol to be usable within the `with` statement. (see [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/))

Comment: Ah ok... seems the Database object doesn't